# How can I group(map) by data for ID?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I group my data by `CustomerID`?

It's does not work, I am trying different way but I think I don't understand this structure

This is my code:

```
function CustomerGroup() {
this.$http.post(auth.API_URL + 'api/ProblemsSupports/ProblemsList', null, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth.getAuthHeader()
    }
}).then((response) => {
    this.problemitems = response.body
    const map = this.problemitems.map(e => (map[e.CustomerID] = map[e.CustomerID]))
    return map
    this.progress = false
}, (response) => {
    if (response.status === 0) {
        this.text1 = ' !!!'
        this.snackbar = true
        this.progress = false
    } else {
        this.text1 = '!!!!!!'
        this.snackbar = true
        this.progress = false
    }
})
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? what is actually happening ?

Comment: I have diffrent problems value. I need to group this problems for customerID , for example  - X COMPANY  - 40 Problems  -   Y COMPANY  - 50 Problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use this function:

```
groupBy (list, keyValue) {
const map = new Map()
list.forEach((item) => {
  const key = item[keyValue]
  const collection = map.get(key)
  if (!collection) {
    map.set(key, [item])
  } else {
    collection.push(item)
  }
})
return Array.from(map.values())  
}
```

then just call it

```
const map = groupBy(this.problemitems, 'CustomerID')
```

You can use function in Vue methods, then don't forget `this`